# How to increase time for password-protected screensaver

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, password-policy, user-settings

I run a network with server 2012 r2, I have users in active directory.

The computers lock after 5 minutes of inactivity. Is there any way to extend the time to 1 hour?

Answer (score 2):

Since your question is tagged with Group Policy, I am thinking you mean this:

[image: screensaver timeout]

It is a per-user setting, so make sure you link the GPO to an OU that contains the user accounts (as opposed to computer accounts) for which you want to control this setting.

Comment: Hi , this didn't work, I don't think it's about screen saver as Windows 10 don't have one, is there any other option to be considered as users complaining about computer prompt them to enter the password is they was inactive for 5 minutes?